# How to properly configure task queue to run 30 tasks per hour?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I should run only 30 tasks per hour and maximum 2 tasks per minute. I am not sure how to configure these 2 conditions at the same time. Currently I have the following setup:

```
- name: task-queue
  rate: 2/m # 2 tasks per minute
  bucket_size: 1
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 0
    min_backoff_seconds: 10
```

But I don't understand how to add first condition there.

Comment: What do you mean "first condition"? Task are entered to a task queue from the code, or by cron jobs. If you want to run a cron, you should be editing `cron.yaml`

Comment: The docs don't specify you being able to say `rate: 30/h` and `rate: 2/s` at the same time. I don't think you can do both.

Comment: @MeLight, first condition is "30 tasks per hour", second condition is "2 tasks per minute"

Comment: I dont think you can do that. If you have a heavy job, or an API use limit, you could define one limit in `queue.yaml` and the other limit inside the task. And don't do expensive work is your timer is not up.